# chrome ignoring my tab index

Tags: html, google-chrome, safari

I've a page in which I've disabled all tabs by adding tabindex="-1" to all links/form elements.

This works in ff/ie but not in chrome/safari.

Any idea if there's a non javascript fix to this?

Comment: `tabindex="-1"` works as it should on Chrome 15. Can you show us your code? On a side-note: Only do this if you absolutely have to. There are people who actually use these features...

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, you can do it like:

> tabindex="#"